# Probability - very difficult combinatorial question - don't have the theoretical background

Tags: combinatorics

"A student sits 6 examination papers, each worth 100 marks. In how many possible ways can he score 40% of the total possible marks?" I could not think of a way to attack this from first principles and thought there must be some theoretical generality that would make it quite easy. Haven't done any serious mathematics for almost 50 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there are just two papers worth $100$ points each, and we want to know the number of ways to score a total of $137$ points, say. It is a well known "trick" to consider the product
$$\bigl(1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{99}+x^{100}\bigr)\cdot \bigl(1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{99}+x^{100}\bigr)\ .$$
Each possible pair  $(p,q)$ of scores gives a term $x^p\cdot x^q=x^s$ with $s=p+q$ in the expansion of this product. Therefore each outcome $(p,q)$ with $p+q=137$ will contribute $1\cdot x^{137}$ to this expansion. It follows that the coefficient of $x^{137}$ in this expansion gives the total number of ways to reach a total score of $137$. Now generalize:

The number $N$ we are looking for is the coefficient of $x^{240}$ in the expansion of
$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{100} x^j\right)^6=\left({1-x^{101}\over 1-x}\right)^6= \sum_{k=0}^6{6\choose k}\bigl(-x^{101}\bigr)^k\ \cdot\ \sum_{l=0}^\infty {-6\choose l}(-x)^l\ .$$
Only the following pairs $(k,l)$ give a contribution: $(0,240)$, $(1,139)$, $(2,38)$. It follows that
$$N=1\cdot{-6\choose 240}+6\cdot{-6\choose 139}+15\cdot{-6\choose38}=4\,188\,528\,351\ .$$

Comment: Thank you! Many years since I studied any mathematics. I presume you're invoking some well-known theorem in the original assertion of the solution (about the coefficient)

Answer (score 0):

If we $e_i$ iqs the score in exam i, we want to know the numbers of combinaisons $(e_1,\cdots,e_6)$ such that :

$$\forall i, 0\leq e_i \leq 100$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^6 e_i = 240$$

And Here I guess, the best way is to consider the general problem with $n$ exams and $p$ points.

You then have the reccurence relation

$$S(n,p) = \sum_{i=0}^{100} S(n-1,p-i)$$

The problem here is that you need to be carefull when $n$ is small, as you can't have $100n > p$